# Sefaradi Tefillin Hand Wrapping

Tags: minhag, tefilin, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, practical-kabbalah

I'm curious about the significance of the standard Sefaradi minhag of [creating a daled on the hand with the tefillin retzuot in two sets of parallel lines](https://bethhamidrash.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/tefillin.jpg)? The [Baghdadi/Hacham Ovadia method](https://www.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/329282918/display_1500/stock-photo-jewish-man-wrapped-in-tefillin-pray-a-religious-orthodox-jew-with-arm-tefillin-on-his-left-hand-329282918.jpg) seems to look more like a daled at a glance. Is there a remez or kabbalistic symbolism in creating the hashtag shape?

Comment: There’s not really a lot of significance in tefillin wraps other than custom and tradition. Btw, Teimanim wrap like the second example you provided.